# Need help identifying plant

Tags: identification

I planted this quite a few months back and it just keeps growing. Recently these white flowers sprouted but i still have no idea what it is.[image: i thought it was a gooseneck or whatever but I don't really think it's that]

Answer (score 3):

That looks a lot like a pokeweed. When you say you planted it, where did it come from? Where are you located?

Comment: Yep, definitely pokeweed. Do NOT let it go to seed, as the seeds are easily spread by birds. Also note that pokeweed is poisonous.

Comment: @Jurp when you say it is easily spread by birds, you are right - because (assuming OP is in eastern north America) it is a native food source for these birds. I would say that in a natural setting on the edge of a yard woods interface you should leave it be. However, there is no reason to have one of these growing in a pot in your yard.

Comment: @renesis - Good point about pokeweed as a food source for birds. It's truly a case of a plant that's a wildflower in its native habitat and a weed in the garden.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the color of the bird poop generated by these berries is deep purple. Keep that in mind if you have a car parked outside and have these plants around your yard. (Speaking from experience.)